# Tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse una función

Tags: python, spyder

Necesito calcular el tiempo promedio (en segundos) qué tarda en ejecutarse la función `function` con los datos de entrada `vect`.
Mientras `t_accum` sea menor a 0.5 segundos tengo que crear una copia del vector e invocar a la función que queremos medir pasándole la copia del vector. Además tengo que acumular en `t_accum` el tiempo de ejecución de esta función. Para ello hay que llamar a `time.process_time()` antes y después, la diferencia será una estimación de ese tiempo de ejecución. Tengo que ir actualizando las repeticiones y devolver el tiempo promedio (tiempo total / número de repeticiones)

```
import time

def measure_time(function, vect):
    t_accum = 0 
    repeticiones = 0  **cuenta el numero de veces que ejecutamos la función**

    while t_accum < 0.5 : 
        copia = vect.copy
        final = time.process_time(t_accum)
        tiempo_promedio = final/repeticiones

return tiempo_promedio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo he entendido, la idea sería ejecutar la función de forma repetida hasta que el tiempo acumulado de las ejecuciones sea mayor a 0.5 segundos. En ese caso, debes llamar a `time.process_time()` justo antes de llamar a la función y de nuevo justo después, obteniendo la diferencia. La idea es evitar que se tenga en consideración también el tiempo de ejecución de la función que mide, así como la de la copia del propio vector.

```
import time

def measure_time(function, vect):
    t_accum = 0 
    repeticiones = 0

    while t_accum < 0.5 : 
        copia = vect.copy()
        t0 = time.process_time()
        function(copia)
        t1 = time.process_time()
        t_accum += t1 - t0 
        repeticiones += 1
        print((f"Ejecución {repeticiones}:"
               f"    T. ejec: {t1 - t0:5f}"
               f"    T. acum: {t_accum:5f}")
              )
    tiempo_promedio = t_accum / repeticiones
    print(f"{'-' * 54}\nT. Promedio: {tiempo_promedio:5f}")
    return tiempo_promedio
```

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> measure_time(np.sum, np.arange(100000000))
>
> Ejecución 1:    T. ejec: 0.051939    T. acum: 0.051939
> Ejecución 2:    T. ejec: 0.076700    T. acum: 0.128639
> Ejecución 3:    T. ejec: 0.052828    T. acum: 0.181467
> Ejecución 4:    T. ejec: 0.069067    T. acum: 0.250534
> Ejecución 5:    T. ejec: 0.052714    T. acum: 0.303248
> Ejecución 6:    T. ejec: 0.069172    T. acum: 0.372420
> Ejecución 7:    T. ejec: 0.053236    T. acum: 0.425657
> Ejecución 8:    T. ejec: 0.072095    T. acum: 0.497751
> Ejecución 9:    T. ejec: 0.053872    T. acum: 0.551623
> ------------------------------------------------------
> T. Promedio: 0.061291
> ```

Los prints son solo para mostrar el proceso paso a paso.

Answer (score 0):

Podía ser algo así:

```py
from time import perf_counter

def measure_time(function, vect):
    t_accum = 0 
    repeticiones = 0

    inicio = final = perf_counter()

    while (final - inicio) <= 0.5:
        repeticiones += 1
        copia = vect.copy()
        function(vect)
        final = perf_counter()

    tiempo_promedio = (final - inicio) / repeticiones

    return tiempo_promedio
```

De todos modos, te aconsejo que mires el módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) para estas cosas.